# How to autowire util:list?

Tags: java, spring

I try to inject into juni test run with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner this bean:

```
<util:list id="MyList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>val1</value>
    <value>val2</value>
    <value>val3</value>
</util:list>
```

In test case MyTestCase:
    @Resource (mappedName="MyList")
    @Qualifier("MyList") 
        private List myList;

But always receive exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

```
Error creating bean MyTestCase
...................
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean
 of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [collection of 
java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate 
for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations:   {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, 
mappedName=, description=, name=, 
type=class java.lang.Object, 
authenticationType=CONTAINER),       

 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=MyList)}
```

What can be the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Resource(name="MyList")
private List<String> list;
```

If it doesn't work, set the `name` of the bean. The `@Qualifier` annotation works if you've used `<qualifier>`

Comment: Can you explain why @Autowired @Qualifier("MyList") fails, but @Resource("MyList") works?